# AntDesign select menu, want to only show part of the option when selected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

So i have this AntDesign Select menu

```
<CustomSelect defaultValue={weeklyImp} dropdownMatchSelectWidth={180} dropdownStyle={{textAlign: "center"}} onChange={handleWeeklyImpChange}>
       <Option value="0" >0 - red</Option>
       <Option value="1" >1 - green</Option>
       <Option value="2">2 - blue (after red)</Option>
</CustomSelect>
```

Now the list of options as you can see is `0 - red` etc.
However when i click on `1 - green` for example, I want the value written inside that select box to be just `1`.

Is that something weird to ask? I cant really find it anywhere in the [Select docs](https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-search)

Comment: Have you checked the title property of [Option](https://ant.design/components/select/#Option-props)?

Comment: oh, i didnt. Seems like what i need but it doesnt seem to be working for me. Im doing `<Option value="0" title="0" >0 - red</Option>`, isnt that right? Doesnt work, still shows `0 - red` in the box

Comment: you can control the displayed value in your select box using its `value` prop. you can just push the selected value to state (in the `onChange`) and then read it from the value prop with something like `<Select value={this.state.value.replace(/^\d - /, '')`. I think it's even better to remove those numbers completely and make it like `<Option value="red">red</Option>` if you know you don't need them

Comment: wait what? No i dont wanna get rid of the numbers. And Im confused as to what youre doing. You used the `Select` component when manipulating the value? Shouldnt that be `Option`? Also, the display value isnt the value prop. The displayed value is whatever you write between the opening and closing tags. `<Option value="0"> Displayed value <Option />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state like this

```
const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState();
```

You will also need a function like this

```
const funcShowOnlyPhoneCode = (value) => {
    setSelectedCode(`${value.substr(0,1)}`);
    console.log('value: ', value);
    return value;
};
```

Then in the JSX you add `onChange={funcShowOnlyPhoneCode}`

```
<CustomSelect onChange={funcShowOnlyPhoneCode} defaultValue={selectedColor} dropdownMatchSelectWidth={180} dropdownStyle={{textAlign: "center"}} onChange={handleWeeklyImpChange}>
  <Option value="0" >0 - red</Option>
  <Option value="1" >1 - green</Option>
  <Option value="2">2 - blue (after red)</Option>
</CustomSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `label` in `Option` and adding another property `optionLabelProp` in `Select`

```
<CustomSelect defaultValue={weeklyImp} dropdownMatchSelectWidth={180} dropdownStyle={{textAlign: "center"}} onChange={handleWeeklyImpChange} optionLabelProp="label">
       <Option value="0" label="0">0 - red</Option>
       <Option value="1" label="1">1 - green</Option>
       <Option value="2" label="2">2 - blue (after red)</Option>
</CustomSelect>
```